# strip ' from all members in a list

Tags: python, list, formatting, strip

Ok, so I converted each line in a text file into a member of a list by doing the following:  
`chkseq=[line.strip() for line in open("sequence.txt")]` 
 So when I  print chkseq I get this: 
 `['3','3']`
 What I would like is for it to instead look like this: 
 `[3,3]`
 I know this is possible, I'm just unsure of how! I need them to be intergers, not strings. So if all else fails, that is my main goal in this: create a list from a .txt file whose members are intergers (which would be all the .txt file contained). 
Thanks!! -OSFTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to interpret the strings as integers. Use `int` to do this:

```
chkseq = [int(line) for line in open("sequence.txt")]
```

It can also be written using `map` instead of a list comprehension:

```
chkseq = map(int, open("sequence.txt"))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you! Will select as answer after 8 min time window :)

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the elements of your list and print them out with your preferred formatting rather than relying on the default formatting when printing the whole list at once.

Answer (score 0):

Say your array is called input, and you want to store the value in an array called chkseq, your code would be:

```
chkseq = [int(i) for i in input]
```

Or, if you wanted to do everything all in one line:

```
chkseq = [int(i.strip()) for i in open("sequence.txt")]
```

Comment: `in` is a keyword - there is no way the array could possibly be called `in`!

Comment: yup, I noticed that and fixed it right after I submitted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string to the `int` constructor will attempt to turn it into a `int`.

```
>>> int('3')
3
>>> int('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```